# How to upload images via Broadleaf admin

Tags: java, broadleaf-commerce

I am unable to upload a product image in broadleaf commerce via the broadleaf admin site. When I try to upload image from a local file, I get the following error

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /admin/asset/uploadAsset. Reason:

    File operation attempted on file that is not in provided work area. D:\DOCUME~1\Gutha\LOCALS~1\Temp\5e\a2\gal_w01.jpg.  Work area = D:\DOCUME~1\Gutha\LOCALS~1\Temp\/5e/a2/
```

I tried creating that folder, and placing the image in that area, but it is of no use becaues each time a new folder is being shown here. Could any one tell me where should I place the images to be uploaded?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug.   I've opened a ticket that you can track here ... 
https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce/issues/773

If you can, let us know what version you are running into the issue in the above ticket.

FYI, I work for Broadleaf Commerce.

Comment: I am running 3.1.0 GA (currently latest version)

Comment: I am also unable to view existing product images while working on the broadleaf, the path of the images in html file is `/cmsstatic/img/sauces/....` but that path doesn't exist in the workspace (mycompany) folder, it is `/img/sauces` instead should be used. How could I correct it?